# laravel Storage::get returns weird characters

Tags: php, laravel

I save file in a folder storage using $file::store('storage'), downloading it is works fine but when I try to get the content using Storage::get($path) it returns weird charcaters like the screenshot bellow. [image]

-Tried Storage::get($path) where $path is the path to file: ex-> $path = "storage/namef.png"
Iexpected the content of the file so I can encoding it later using base64_encode

Comment: "_I expected the content of the file_" Those _weird_ characters _are_ the contents of your file. You need to send an appropriate header for your browser to recognize it as such

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @brombeer yes you are right, actually  I was trying to do an api that  encodes (base_64) the file  presents in storage and return the result . the API should return [ encoded file, mime_type stored in a table ( when the file is uploaded the fisrt time), and the original name]